# How to read and write data through Java Nio client in Android

Tags: android, client, nio

I am doing Client server communication in java successfully but now i need to write client in Android rather the java.

client: public class ExampleClient2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
    int port = 1114;
    SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();


    // we open this channel in non blocking mode
    channel.configureBlocking(false);
    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.88", port));

    if(!channel.isConnected())
    {
        while (!channel.finishConnect()) {
            System.out.println("still connecting");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("connected...");


    while (true) {
        // see if any message has been received
        ByteBuffer bufferA = ByteBuffer.allocate(60);
        int count = 0;
        String message = "";
        while ((count = channel.read(bufferA)) > 0) {
            // flip the buffer to start reading
            bufferA.flip();
            message += Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bufferA);

        }

        if (message.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("message " + message); 
            if(message.contains("stop"))
            {
                System.out.println("Has stop messages");
                //                  break;
            }
            else
            {
                // write some data into the channel
                CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello Server stop from client2 from 88");
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    channel.write(Charset.defaultCharset().encode(buffer));
                }
            }
            message = "";
        }

    }
}
```

}

this code is running successfully in java but in android it consuming lots of memory and not running reliably, due to its while (true) loop its like polling , plz let me know some solution that without polling i can read and write the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `compact()` the buffer after calling `decode()` (or `get()`, or `write()`, anything that takes data out of the buffer).

Youu shouldn't allocate a new buffer every time around that `while` loop, and you should break out of it if `read()` returned -1. I don't actually see a need for the `while` loop at all.

Comment: if i remove while loop,client will terminated instantly. it will not listened any received message.